# How to pluck data from inter related tables using laravel eloquent relationsips

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get email of those customers who has requested for a trip,

I have three table `trips`, `service_requests`, `users`

Here is how my tables are related

In Trips model

```
 public function requests(){
        return $this->hasMany(ServiceRequest::class);
    }
```

In ServiceRequest Model

```
public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "customer_id");
    }
```

This is the code I am using to get results, I am getting the results that I want, but I just want to get only the array of email addresses of customers

```
 $trip_customers = Trip::with('requests.customer')
                ->whereHas('requests', function($query){
                    $query->where('status', 2);
                })->get()->pluck('requests');
```

The output of the above is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [customer_id] => 1
                    [post_ad_id] => 
                    [trip_id] => 1
                    [pickup_date] => 2020-06-15
                    [dropoff_date] => 2020-06-18
                    [address] => Lane C 20, Gokul Enclave
                    [contact_no] => 8451515
                    [weight] => 681
                    [person] => 
                    [additional_comments] => eretrt
                    [status] => 2
                    [view_status] => 1
                    [customer] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Customer
                            [email] => customer@xyz.com
                            [mobile_number] => 51551
                            [status] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to come in from the Customer side since you only need information from that table:

```
Customer::whereHas('requests', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 2);
})->pluck('email');
```

Assuming Customer has a relationship back to ServiceRequest.

Comment: But there is another tabe trip, for which the customer has requested for

Comment: and the reason I am querying this on trip is because if some user wishes to cancel his trip, all the customer who requested for it will get an email notification

Comment: this would give you the email addresses of all the customers who have service_requests with status of 2 for any trip ... if you want to filter by trip then you can do that in the whereHas since that there is a trip_id field there  ... if you want to keep what you currently have but just extract the customer's emails from it, that can be done as well :)

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain the complete scenario in one go, what I need is I have a listing of trips on the dashboard and If i choose to cancel a particular trip I click on the cancel button which hits a method in my controller that takes trip_id as a parameter, now I only want to send mail to those customers who requested for that particular trip.

Comment: add a `where` to the `whereHas` query for the `trip_id` you need